# Can I do this rearrangement with an infinite series to arrive at divergent parts?

Tags: infinity, divergent-series

$$\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{i}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)\left(i+1\right)} = \sum_{i=3}^\infty \frac{2}{3\left(i-2\right)} - \frac{1}{2\left(i-1\right)} - \frac{1}{6\left(i+1\right)} \\**= \frac{2}{3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) - 1\right) - \frac{1}{6}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) - 1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right)** \\= \left(\frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{18} \\= 0\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) + \frac{29}{36} \\= \frac{29}{36} \space or \space \infty?$$

When summing up the series above I came by the harmonic series multiplied by $0$. I simply equated it to be $0$ while my friend keeps arguing that the harmonic series is an infinity and infinity multiplied by $0$ is undefined. Now I find it difficult to argue with it. ***Does this mean that the series above diverge?***

Or maybe I was thinking, in the starred line, the $\frac{2}{3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) - \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right)$ is cancelling out anyway, right? I mean I could just right it term by term and show every term cancels. ***If they are cancelling out then this rearrangement should not be problematic, right? So, am I right to say that $0\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}\right) = 0$ to show its convergence?***

Comment: What is your summand for $i=1$ and for $i=2$?

Comment: The series is undefined, since for $i=1$ and $i=2$ there is a division by $0$

Comment: Sorry it started with $i = 3$. I've edited it now

Comment: Bear in mind that the original sum is a limit, so if you run into an undefined piece, simply substitute $\infty $ with a large integer $N$ and see what you are left with and what happens in the limit.

Comment: That the series actually converges can be seen by considering that the expression is asymptotically $\frac{1}{i^2}$ and the sum over this is well known to converge.

Comment: To avoid your question being closed, you might think about changing the subject into something like "Can I do this rearranging of an infinite series to arrive at divergent part" or so. Then the given answers "make" also automatically "more sense" for your question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the series begins from $i=3$, it will converge, but you need to be more careful with the manipulation of the series, you can't just split the series in three. The theorem that would allow you to split series doesn't apply here:

$$\sum_n (a_n - b_n) = \sum_n a_n - \sum_n b_n$$

IF $ \sum_n a_n$ AND $\sum_n b_n$ CONVERGE.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** This question was radically rewritten. I was answering the original question: *What is 0 multiplied with a divergent series with summation of infinity?*

The series (the fixed variant) [converges, its sum is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bx%2F%28%28x%20-%201%29%20%28x%20-%202%29%20%28x%20%2B%201%29%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%203%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D) $\frac{29}{36}.$

As to the separate question of zero being multiplied by a divergent series, the main algebraic property of zero is that it multiplied by anything is still zero, and this is usually taken as the stronger rule than multiplication by something infinite. Even in the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) ${\overline {\mathbb {R} }}$ while $0\cdot\infty$ is often left undefined, in many cases there is a solid justification to define it as $0$.

Answer (score -2):

Well you can use this method for verification

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{i}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{(i-1)(i+1)+1}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1)(i-1)}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(i-2\right)(i)}+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{i-(i-2)}{\left(i-2\right)(i)}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1)-(i-2)}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)\left(i+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\left(i-2\right)}-\frac{1}{i})+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\left(i-2\right)\left(i-1\right)(i)}-\frac{1}{\left(i-1\right)\left(i\right)(i+1)})$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{6})$

$\displaystyle\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{18}={\frac{29}{36}}$